# SQL Query, Sum the same entry from ID multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I first ran a query to get the item ID,

```
SELECT ITEM 
FROM `SALES` 
WHERE DATE>='2018-2-1' AND DATE<='2018-2-5' AND CASH_CREDIT='1'
```

Which returned the results; 1,3,7,4,8,7,5,1

I need to use those ID numbers to add the RETAIL_PRICE of each item together.
I've tried the following but it didn't allow for the item ID to be used more than once so it only added the RETAIL_PRICE from 1,3,7,4,8,5 which leaves out the values from the other 7 and 1. I need to add them with those 2 values included.

```
SELECT SUM(RETAIL_PRICE) 
FROM `ITEMS` 
WHERE ID IN(1,3,7,4,8,7,5,1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about, SELECT sum(retail_price) FROM `SALES` s join `items` i on s.item=i.id whERE s.DATE>='2018-2-1' AND s.dATE<='2018-2-5' AND s.CASH_CREDIT='1'

Comment: You can't. You have to explicitly state what you want with the sum itself. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for further help.

Comment: The RETAIL_PRICE is stored in a seperate table called ITEMS so that did not work

Comment: I assume you revised the answer? That now works perfectly. Thanks RizkiD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in `ITEMS` table, we can use a JOIN operation, to get *all* the rows that match, and the add up the retail price from each of the rows.

```
SELECT SUM(i.retail_price) AS tot_retail_price 
  FROM `ITEMS` i 
  JOIN `SALES` s
    ON s.item = i.id
 WHERE s.date        >= '2018-02-01'
   AND s.date        <  '2018-02-06'
   AND s.cash_credit =  '1'
```

---

As you observed, this condtion

```
WHERE ID IN (1,3,7,4,8,7,5,1)
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE ID IN (1,3,4,5,7,8)
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE ID IN (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8)
```

That query is one pass through the table, evaluating each row in the table. It doesn't matter how many times a value is repeated in the `IN` list.  The condition is evaluated, and either a row satisfies the condition or it doesn't. The condition is TRUE or FALSE (or NULL).